# Laravel Storage Cache folders owned by root causes fail in clearing cache

Tags: php, laravel, caching, root

I have a laravel 7 application running on a server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, apache2 webserver). My problem is, that `php artisan cache:clear` does return "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions."

I tried the following approaches without success:

- `chmod -R 775 storage`
- `php artisan config:cache`
- manually deleting "bootstrap/cache/services.php" + "bootstrap/cache/packages.php" + "bootstrap/cache/config.php"

New created cache folders in "storage/framework/cache/data" are sometimes owned by user root, this seems to be the problem.

If I delete these folders manually it works till new root folders are created.

With `ps -aux` I saw that the laravel process was running from user root. I changed this with `sudo -u myusername`, but this didnt change the behaviour. I am starting the laravel application (`php artisan serve`) within the rc.local script on server restart.

The current user "myusername" is in the group www-data.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the stackoverflow. What webserver under what OS did you use? In general - you should add your current user and user which start webserver to one common user group.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried to enhance my question.

Comment: Try edit rc.local like this `su user01 -c 'php /var/www/artisan serve'` where `user01` is your current user and `/var/www/artisan` is full path to your artisan file. Also maybe you should specify full path to your php bin file, like `/usr/bin/php` or else. More details here https://serverfault.com/questions/422950/execute-script-from-rc-local-as-user-instead-of-root

Comment: I changed it in the described way and it seems to work. Thank you :), If you make a post I can accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad it helps. I add the answer, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run webserver from the user that is belongs to the same usergroup with your current user. By default `rc.local` call commands from `root` user, which is not what you need.

Edit your `rc.local` this way:

```sh
su user01 -c 'php /var/www/artisan serve'
```

Where `user01` is your current user and `/var/www/artisan` is full path to your artisan file. Also maybe you should specify full path to your php bin file, like `/usr/bin/php` or else.

More details [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/422950/execute-script-from-rc-local-as-user-instead-of-root)

Answer (score -2):

The problem should be that you don't have folders in storage path. You should have

1. storage/framework/sessions
2. storage/framework/views
3. storage/framework/cache

Try to create empty folders, it should be work.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. All those folders are and were existing. So unfortunately this is not the problem.